# Budget GPU for Ryzen 5 1600 on ASUS PRIME X370-PRO to play 4k video?

Tags: graphics-cards, video

I have around 200€ to spend on a graphics card to go together with my Ryzen 5 1600 CPU on an ASUS PRIME X370-PRO mobo. My goal is to be able to play 4k 60Hz video on one monitor. Neither gaming nor mining nor deep-learning are the goal. So, I am ok with 128-bit memory bus and as low as 2GBs of GDDR5 RAM. The physical size of the card is not an issue, it is a plus if it is power-efficient and high quality. Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of 4K video? The processing power required will vary vastly depending on codec and bitrate.